# Paint a specific pallet element in a specified grid position using c# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know how to refer to a specific grid position in unity, so I can either paint a new tile on it or destroy an old one by using a script. I want to refer to a specific tile as shown in this picture:

[image: unity image]

and paint something from the palatte there.

I'm trying to create an auto scroller, so I want to be able to fill in new tiles on the fly and destroy the old ones. Sorry if this is something obvious I'm new to unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vector3int and [SetTile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html) to specify the position and paint the tile on your grid.

```
Tilemap myMap; 
TileBase myTile;
Vector3int tilePosition;
//assign your values to these variables

myMap.setTile(tilePosition, myTile);
```

to remove a tile you can use `setTile(tilePosition, null);`

To use the Tilemap class you will likely to need to include the library.

```
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
```

Comment: How can I set a specific tile to the TileBase variable, I'm trying to dig through the documentation but can't quite seem to find it. For example I have a tile called GroundTile and I would like to use it when using the SetTile method, how can I refer to it specifically or do I need to set the class to be serializable and use the unity inspector to specify the asset I want to use?

Comment: Either would work. You can either assign through the unity inspector or use Resources.Load to grab it